# MySQL hanging when using UPDATE CASE WHEN for saving reordering list

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `MySQL` `UPDATE CASE WHEN ELSE` statement to update an ordered list on my web application. I have a `html table` with the `sortable` `drag-and-drop` plugin, and on the `stop event` I hit a `servlet` that persists the new order to the `MySQL Table`.

The thing is that from time to time `MySQL` hangs when the user reorders the table very quickly. Like in the example below, there were 4 statements issued in the same second, and then it hanged.

```
22/01/2014 14:03:25 UPDATE `edited_table_name` SET `order` = CASE NR_DMD WHEN 92059 THEN 22 WHEN 124376 THEN 23 WHEN 124163 THEN 24 WHEN 127019 THEN 25 WHEN 123816 THEN 26 WHEN 124348 THEN 27 WHEN 127017 THEN 28 WHEN 126764 THEN 29 WHEN 126637 THEN 30 WHEN 122170 THEN 31 WHEN 125630 THEN 32 WHEN 125515 THEN 33 WHEN 124487 THEN 34 WHEN 124374 THEN 35 WHEN 124343 THEN 36 WHEN 124327 THEN 37 WHEN 126838 THEN 38 WHEN 126720 THEN 39 WHEN 126718 THEN 40 WHEN 123510 THEN 41 WHEN 122966 THEN 42 WHEN 124385 THEN 43 WHEN 122754 THEN 44 WHEN 124312 THEN 45 WHEN 122311 THEN 46 WHEN 121577 THEN 47 WHEN 121028 THEN 48 WHEN 123354 THEN 49 WHEN 121682 THEN 50 WHEN 120993 THEN 51 WHEN 120860 THEN 52 WHEN 120750 THEN 53 WHEN 120460 THEN 54 WHEN 120459 THEN 55 WHEN 120397 THEN 56 WHEN 119178 THEN 57 WHEN 111723 THEN 58 WHEN 127644 THEN 59 WHEN 127610 THEN 60 WHEN 127609 THEN 61 WHEN 127542 THEN 62 WHEN 125799 THEN 63 ELSE order END WHERE NR_DMD IN(92059,124376,124163,127019,123816,124348,127017,126764,126637,122170,125630,125515,124487,124374,124343,124327,126838,126720,126718,123510,122966,124385,122754,124312,122311,121577,121028,123354,121682,120993,120860,120750,120460,120459,120397,119178,111723,127644,127610,127609,127542,125799)
22/01/2014 14:03:25 UPDATE `edited_table_name` SET `order` = CASE NR_DMD WHEN 121419 THEN 10 WHEN 110378 THEN 11 WHEN 124376 THEN 12 WHEN 124163 THEN 13 WHEN 127019 THEN 14 WHEN 123816 THEN 15 WHEN 124348 THEN 16 WHEN 127017 THEN 17 WHEN 126764 THEN 18 WHEN 126637 THEN 19 WHEN 122170 THEN 20 WHEN 125630 THEN 21 WHEN 125515 THEN 22 WHEN 124487 THEN 23 WHEN 124374 THEN 24 WHEN 124343 THEN 25 WHEN 124327 THEN 26 WHEN 126838 THEN 27 WHEN 126720 THEN 28 WHEN 126718 THEN 29 WHEN 123510 THEN 30 WHEN 122966 THEN 31 WHEN 124385 THEN 32 WHEN 122754 THEN 33 WHEN 124312 THEN 34 WHEN 122311 THEN 35 WHEN 121577 THEN 36 ELSE order END WHERE NR_DMD IN(121419,110378,124376,124163,127019,123816,124348,127017,126764,126637,122170,125630,125515,124487,124374,124343,124327,126838,126720,126718,123510,122966,124385,122754,124312,122311,121577)
22/01/2014 14:03:25 UPDATE `edited_table_name` SET `order` = CASE NR_DMD WHEN 127585 THEN 21 WHEN 124376 THEN 22 WHEN 124163 THEN 23 WHEN 127019 THEN 24 WHEN 123816 THEN 25 WHEN 124348 THEN 26 WHEN 127017 THEN 27 WHEN 126764 THEN 28 WHEN 126637 THEN 29 WHEN 122170 THEN 30 WHEN 125630 THEN 31 WHEN 125515 THEN 32 WHEN 124487 THEN 33 WHEN 124374 THEN 34 WHEN 124343 THEN 35 WHEN 124327 THEN 36 WHEN 126838 THEN 37 WHEN 126720 THEN 38 WHEN 126718 THEN 39 WHEN 123510 THEN 40 WHEN 122966 THEN 41 WHEN 124385 THEN 42 WHEN 122754 THEN 43 WHEN 124312 THEN 44 WHEN 122311 THEN 45 WHEN 121577 THEN 46 WHEN 121028 THEN 47 WHEN 123354 THEN 48 WHEN 121682 THEN 49 WHEN 120993 THEN 50 WHEN 120860 THEN 51 WHEN 120750 THEN 52 WHEN 120460 THEN 53 WHEN 120459 THEN 54 WHEN 120397 THEN 55 WHEN 119178 THEN 56 WHEN 111723 THEN 57 WHEN 127644 THEN 58 WHEN 127610 THEN 59 WHEN 127609 THEN 60 ELSE order END WHERE NR_DMD IN(127585,124376,124163,127019,123816,124348,127017,126764,126637,122170,125630,125515,124487,124374,124343,124327,126838,126720,126718,123510,122966,124385,122754,124312,122311,121577,121028,123354,121682,120993,120860,120750,120460,120459,120397,119178,111723,127644,127610,127609)
22/01/2014 14:03:25 UPDATE `edited_table_name` SET `order` = CASE NR_DMD WHEN 127638 THEN 19 WHEN 127592 THEN 20 WHEN 124376 THEN 21 WHEN 124163 THEN 22 WHEN 127019 THEN 23 WHEN 123816 THEN 24 WHEN 124348 THEN 25 WHEN 127017 THEN 26 WHEN 126764 THEN 27 WHEN 126637 THEN 28 WHEN 122170 THEN 29 WHEN 125630 THEN 30 WHEN 125515 THEN 31 WHEN 124487 THEN 32 WHEN 124374 THEN 33 WHEN 124343 THEN 34 WHEN 124327 THEN 35 WHEN 126838 THEN 36 WHEN 126720 THEN 37 WHEN 126718 THEN 38 WHEN 123510 THEN 39 WHEN 122966 THEN 40 WHEN 124385 THEN 41 WHEN 122754 THEN 42 WHEN 124312 THEN 43 WHEN 122311 THEN 44 WHEN 121577 THEN 45 WHEN 121028 THEN 46 WHEN 123354 THEN 47 WHEN 121682 THEN 48 WHEN 120993 THEN 49 WHEN 120860 THEN 50 WHEN 120750 THEN 51 WHEN 120460 THEN 52 WHEN 120459 THEN 53 WHEN 120397 THEN 54 WHEN 119178 THEN 55 WHEN 111723 THEN 56 WHEN 127644 THEN 57 ELSE order END WHERE NR_DMD IN(127638,127592,124376,124163,127019,123816,124348,127017,126764,126637,122170,125630,125515,124487,124374,124343,124327,126838,126720,126718,123510,122966,124385,122754,124312,122311,121577,121028,123354,121682,120993,120860,120750,120460,120459,120397,119178,111723,127644)
```

I thought MySQL would deal with the simultaneous hits on the same table. But it looks like not. Perhaps it's some issue with table locks.

If you can give me any advice in any configuration or technique or even another better way to persist the reordered list, I'd be very greateful.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you getting a ERROR 1100: Table locked? Also, have you tried unlocking the tables between each `UPDATE`? - This would help determine if it was caused by the tables being locked.

Comment: Also, are you using innodb or myisam?

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any error on JDBC. At least it's not reaching JDBC. I'll check for MySQL logs. The table's engine is InnoDB.

Comment: When there is a lock, please run the commands SHOW INNODB STATUS and SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST from 2 other sessions. That should tell us what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the following session parameters before your update statement in your servlet.

"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED"

That would allow that if two statements occurs almost instantanously, it would take the latest one even if the other process had not commited it to the server.

For sure it is better to send changes only if the end-user did not did any drag & drop  for more than X seconds (ie: 2) and send only 1 request. That would solve the problem also.

Comment: Wouldn't this worsen the problem?

Comment: In READ COMMITTED the locks that did not match the scan are released after the STATEMENT completes.

Make sure to close the statement and use proper indexes as innodb might lock more rows than the selected one..


use of "show engine innodb status" will tell how how much locks it used... it should match the number of items you have in the NR_DMD where clause..

Something like this would be bad as it would lock 21878 rows but only 1 row (undo log entries 1) is updated... but 218k rows are locked.

633 lock struct(s), <strong>heap size 96696</strong>, 218786 row lock(s), undo log entries 1

Comment: Also on a side note you might want to try to remove the index on "order", as during the update process innodb could potentially lock the index...

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider using something in your client side code so that you don't submit multiple AJAX requests simultaneously such as setTimeout when the list is reordered.

Perhaps something like this:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/examples/ajax/

Comment: Yes. I'm already doing that, but the real issue is why the DB isn't dealing with simultaneous hits.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you maintain a check for a period of inactivity and when there is a good amount of inactivity, send latest update (that has the cumulative update) to the server.

Comment: I don't think is a inactivity problem, since the table is read for various functionalities of the application which has almost no idle time.

Comment: I meant that you should maintain a check for inactivity by the user to fix the changes that should go to the database. Once the user has done the changes, you can reflect it onto the database. Now to determine that the user is done with the changes, for the moment, just check for inactivity in the required UI element and then send the changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

During the execution of your update query InnoDB locks every row that it traverses to find the rows it is modifying. So to reduce the number of locks you can split your query into two separate queries:

1. Get `PRIMARY_KEY_LIST`, suppose that the primary key of `edited_table_name` is `id`

   SELECT id FROM `edited_table_name` WHERE NR_DMD IN(...)
2. Update basing on primary key list

   UPDATE `edited_table_name` SET `order` = CASE... WHERE id IN (PRIMARY_KEY_LIST)

This will reduce the number of locks because it reduces the number of rows that the engine has to traverse.

Another option is to put an index on `NR_DMD` columns

Comment: NR_DMD is the PRIMARY KEY

Comment: If NR_DMD is the PRIMARY KEY, your update queries violate the unique constraint of the key because there are many duplicate values in the update queries. Maybe your application code does not handle it correctly for this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I might have a `handler` to throttle the hits that come to the servlet probably in this scenario :

1. Rather than instantly applying every new order request that hits the servlet , I would store the info/details in a table say `new_order_requests_table` .
2. I would have a `flag` which is used/updated by this handler accordingly with status of itself , say : `Idle` , `Under Progress` , etc .
3. Whenever the above `flag` shows as `Idle` , I would consider to apply the latest row from the `new_order_requests_table` and probably delete all earlier rows from it .

For multiple users , you would need to modify the above accordingly .

> Further , when it is needed to update many rows in a MySQL table in a single statement , sometimes it would be better with MyISAM which does table level locking as opposed to InnoDB which does row level locking . This is because InnoDB might be consuming considerable duration just to  lock and unlock those many rows .
> You could try switching between `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` to find the better suitable engine for this table in your application .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Table1 (
     NR_DMD int NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Table1 (NR_DMD)
   VALUES
(92059),(124376),(124163),(127019),(123816),(124348),(127017),(126764),(126637),
(122170),(125630),(125515),(124487),(124374),(124343),(124327),(126838),(126720),
(126718),(123510),(122966),(124385),(122754),(124312),(122311),(121577),(121028),
(123354),(121682),(120993),(120860),(120750),(120460),(120459),(120397),(119178),
(111723),(127644),(127610),(127609),(127542),(125799);

select * from Table1

22/01/2014 14:03:25 
UPDATE `edited_table_name
` SET `order` = CASE NR_DMD WHEN 92059 THEN 22 WHEN 124376 THEN 23 WHEN 124163 THEN 24 
WHEN 127019 THEN 25 WHEN 123816 THEN 26 WHEN 124348 THEN 27 WHEN 127017 THEN 28
WHEN 126764 THEN 29 WHEN 126637 THEN 30 WHEN 122170 THEN 31
WHEN 125630 THEN 32 WHEN 125515 THEN 33 WHEN 124487 THEN 34 
WHEN 124374 THEN 35 WHEN 124343 THEN 36 WHEN 124327 THEN 37 
WHEN 126838 THEN 38 WHEN 126720 THEN 39 WHEN 126718 THEN 40
WHEN 123510 THEN 41 WHEN 122966 THEN 42 WHEN 124385 THEN 43 
WHEN 122754 THEN 44 WHEN 124312 THEN 45 WHEN 122311 THEN 46
WHEN 121577 THEN 47 WHEN 121028 THEN 48 WHEN 123354 THEN 49
WHEN 121682 THEN 50 WHEN 120993 THEN 51 WHEN 120860 THEN 52 
WHEN 120750 THEN 53 WHEN 120460 THEN 54 WHEN 120459 THEN 55
WHEN 120397 THEN 56 WHEN 119178 THEN 57 WHEN 111723 THEN 58 
WHEN 127644 THEN 59 WHEN 127610 THEN 60 WHEN 127609 THEN 61 
WHEN 127542 THEN 62 WHEN 125799 THEN 63 ELSE order END 
WHERE NR_DMD IN(Select NR_DMD from Table1);
```

**Summary:**

1)Create temp table and insert the values for first update.

2)

```
UPDATE tablename SET ColName =CASE STATEMENT
       Where NR_DMD in ( SELECT NR_DMD FROM temp table)
```

3) Do the same for 2 other update statement.

I think this will help you to better perform.